# What does it mean to have an asterisk on a method name in C?

Tags: c, pointers, methods

I'm familiar with C and pointers, but this part is new to me. Take a look at this method declaration in [godot-headers](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-headers/blob/master/gdnative_api_struct.gen.h#L958):

```c
godot_class_constructor (*godot_get_class_constructor)(const char *p_classname);
```

There is a `*` applied to the method name. Or at least, I think this is a method? There are a lot of method declarations like this, here I just picked the one I'm trying to use. In particular, I noticed that the name of the method with the asterisk (first set of parenthesis) is separate from the list of parameters in the method (second set of parenthesis). I don't know what this means. Method pointer? Dereference method? For context, here is how `godot_class_constructor` is defined:

```c
typedef godot_object *(*godot_class_constructor)();
```

The C source doesn't include an example use case for this, however, here is an example usage from the Godot C++ bindings:

```cpp
static godot_class_constructor base_constructor = godot::api->godot_get_class_constructor(T::___get_godot_class_name());
godot_object *base_obj = base_constructor();
```

I have not been able to replicate the above in C without crashing, but here is my failed attempt:

```c
godot_class_constructor directory_constructor = api->godot_get_class_constructor("Directory");
godot_object *directory = directory_constructor();
```

Comment: It's a [*function pointer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268444/what-are-function-pointers).

Comment: How do I use it?