# Concept of function pointers in C?

Tags: c, embedded

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the point of function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592137/what-is-the-point-of-function-pointers)

hi all,

I want to get the basic and concrete idea of function pointers in C language.
ie 1) its usage in C
   2) main applications it is currently using 
   3) unique features
   4) its scope in embedded applciations etc

Hoping your co operation in this too.

__Kanu

Comment: What research have you done so far? This link is helpful: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/function_pointers.html

Comment: What is the problem in my question to make it as negative???

Comment: It's way too broad for good specific answers. You're asking for 4 different points here.

Comment: There already exists a question that answers what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: but at least you can mark it as ZERO(0) instead of negative as my question is not at all offensive one right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function Pointers are pointers, that is variables, which point to the address of a function.

Nice example [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/intro.html#what). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592137/what-is-the-point-of-function-pointers/2592270#2592270) is a must read.

Comment: I don't think they point to the address of a function so much as they are the address of a function.