# Why there are two ways to call function by pointer?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, visual-c++

In project I'm working with I had found a complex macro that was creating  an map of pointers to functions loaded from shared library. To use it for another library which should be loaded same way I had to inspect that.. and found that it contains line that shouldn't be working as far as I know. To boil down it to simple code, I threw away all syntax sugar and made such example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(int i, float f)
{
    cout << "Parameter is " << i << " and " << f  << endl;
}


typedef void (*FunctionFunc)(int i, float f);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FunctionFunc p = &func;
    (p)(5,4.3f);
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't the function call look like (*p)(5,4.3f) - according to books since K&R's? Compiler is VS2010 and code above works both with asterisk and without.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152167/why-is-using-the-function-name-as-a-function-pointer-equivalent-to-applying-the)

Comment: @user3286661: That's the reverse conversion.

Comment: @MSalters The accepted answer  to that question is a very good answer to this question.

Comment: Well, it was not possible to find that because that question was an answer to my question, lol. The author asked about quite different manifestation of same paradox. I can't say I blame newer standards or that I hate C++, but by piling up  features into standard they caused some issues.

Comment: Fun fact: the function-call operator, `()`, *always* operates on a pointer-to-function.  When you write `(*p)()`, the pointer is dereferenced, _and then immediately un-dereferenced again_ so that the function call operator gets what it wants.  (C99 §§ 6.3.2p4 and 6.5.2.2p1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the dereference is not necessary. Pointers to functions are callable just like functions are. Even `p(5, 4.3f)` would have been acceptable.