# Why can `(*)` be omitted from a function pointer inside a function parameter list?

Tags: c

Compiling with gcc8:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void some_func(void f1(void), void (*f2)(void))
{
    printf("%d\n", f1);
    printf("%d\n", f2);
}
```

Gives (only) the following warnings:

```
<source>:11:14: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'void (*)(void)' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d\n", f1);
<source>:12:14: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'void (*)(void)' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d\n", f2);
```

Why is the type of `f1` the same as `f2`? Only `f2` is declared as a function pointer. I would expect `f1` not to compile at all, as it names a function type, not a function pointer. What is the rule that says, that a function type inside a function parameter list changes to a pointer to that function type?

Comment: Answered this on Quora once: https://www.quora.com/In-C-is-it-possible-to-pass-a-function-to-another-function/answer/Petr-Skocik

Comment: Regarding the warnings, please use `%p` format specifier when targeting pointers.

Comment: @paddy I know, and not really, `%p` is _only_ for `void*`, so I would need to cast it. The warnings serve only to show to me the deduced by the compiler variable types, not to print the pointers addresses.

Comment: As a note, just stick to one style, be constant, I prefer the second one but, there is not a clear rule about that.

Comment: Why? Because the language standard says so.

Comment: @paddy `"%p"` is for `void *`, not necessarily function pointers.  Casting a function pointer to `void*` has its limitations too.  No  great way to print function pointers - `printf("%jX\n", (uintmax_t) f1);` is a reasonable mostly portable alternative.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because the standard ([6.7.6.3p8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p8)) says that

> A declaration of a parameter as ''function returning type'' shall be
>   adjusted to ''pointer to function returning type'', as in [6.3.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3).

It's similar to how [arrays parameters are adjusted to pointers (6.7.63.p7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7) , if you think about it.

```
void some_func(void (void));
void some_func(void (*)(void));
```

are compatible declarations, just like:

```
void other_func(char string[]);
void other_func(char *string);
```

are.

---

Note that the adjustment doesn't make `void some_func(void (*)(void)` compatible with `void some_other_func(void (**)(void)` or `void yet_another_func(void (*****)(void)` and that as far as functions are concerned, declarations don't really reflect use anymore, (despite that being the intention of the language's original author). In standardized C, due to how function identifiers decay to pointers and due to how it doesn't matter whether you use a function type or a function pointer type to make a call, you can call any function with arbitrarily many `*`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    (*puts)("hello world");
    (******puts)("hello world");
    (***&*&*puts)("hello world"); //& cancels a * as per 6.5.3.2p3

    int (*p)(char const*) = puts;
    int (**pp)(char const*) = &p;
    int (***ppp)(char const*) = &pp;

    (**ppp)("hello world"); //at least two asterisks required here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in C, in that case, the function name itself is a function pointer. See this answer: [Why is using the function name as a function pointer equivalent to applying the address-of operator to the function name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152167/why-is-using-the-function-name-as-a-function-pointer-equivalent-to-applying-the)

Comment: Then why does `void some_func(void (*****f3)(void))` here `f3` names a different type then `f1` and `f2`.

Comment: I don't see why it should be the same type as `f1` or `f2`. There is an historical and practical reason why the function name is a pointer to the function itself, like explained in that answer, and I don't see these reasons can be applied to any arbitrary pointer to pointer (...) to function.

Comment: In C, a function name itself is **not** a function pointer. The function name is an identifier. When used as an expression, it has function type. Per C 6.3.2.1 4, an expression that has function type is called a *function designator*. When it is not used as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, **then** a function designator is converted to a pointer (again by 6.3.2.1 4). I understand you may think of this conversion as so automatic and ubiquitous that one can think of a function name as a pointer, but we are creating a permanent record of technical answers explaining the C standard here.

Comment: @EricPostpischil does this mean that you can only call only function pointers and not functions? Because `()` operator is not `sizeof` or `&`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: In a function call expression, such as `SomeExpression()`, if the `SomeExpression` is a function designator (any expression that has function type), then it is automatically converted to a pointer to the function. In effect, a “proper” way to write a function call such as `f1(3)` is `(&f1)(3)`. When you write `f1(3)`, the compiler automatically converts it to `(&f1)(3)` for you.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree, that is what I meant. You never truly call a function, you always call a function pointer.