# Pointer to function why sould I use it?

Tags: c, function, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the point of function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592137/what-is-the-point-of-function-pointers)

I saw this code

```
 void (*foo)(int);
```

And I understood that is pointer to function.

Why should I point to another function what does it give me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it to store a handler function that can be changed according the program flow, like the comparison function supplied to `qsort`.

```
void (*my_handler)(int);

void set_handler(void(*fn)(int)) {
    my_handler = fn;
}

void do_stuff() {
    // ...
    my_handler(x); // using a custom handler
}

if (something) {
    set_handler(my_function_1);
}
else set_handler(my_function_2);    

do_stuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject so a compairer for a sort algorithm. So you can exclude some logic outside.

Or you can implement a callback with this method for some event handling.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are commonly used for callbacks. For example, imagine an asynchronous function that does some heavy work and you want to be notified when its finished:

```
void doWork(void (*foo)(int));
```

When you call that function, it runs in its own thread so it returns immediately. How do you know when it's finished? You tell it to call a function you provide when it's done:

```
void myFoo(int n);
```

and you pass that to `doWork()`:

```
doWork(myFoo);
```

Now when `doWork()` finishes, it will call `myFoo()`.

That's just one use of callbacks, but it's the most common one, I believe.