# All the functions in c are globally defined, then why we need to pass them to function as argument?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

In c, we have to define all the functions globally. while studying function pointer i got some program where programmer passes function name as parameter to other function. so why we need to pass function to other function if they all are globally defined?

here i am giving small sample program :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void bsort(int arr[],int n,int (*compare)(int,int))    //bubble sort
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++){
            if(compare(arr[j],arr[j+1]) > 0 ){
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int compare(int a,int b)
{
    if(a > b) return 1;
    return -1;
}

void main()
{
    int i;
    int arr[5]={6,5,1,9,2};
    bsort(arr,5,compare);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);   
}
```

in this code, if we remove 3rd argument in definition and calling part of bsort function then also our program will give us same output.so for function pointer this program doesn't make sense.
can you please do some modification in this code and make it good example for function pointer.

Thanks.

Comment: `void func()` does not need to be global.  It only needs to be seen by `main()`.  It could be static in same .c file as `main()`.

Comment: You must pass a comparison function for the comparison  of the elements of the case functions such as `bsearch` and `qsort` can not be assumed in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The point of a function pointer is to change the behavior of a particular function at run time.

Comment: Just because they're globally defined in your example, does not mean that this will always be the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the point of function pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592137/what-is-the-point-of-function-pointers)

Comment: If possible please give small code, rather than qsort. because i tried to find my answer on many sites and they all just explaining qsort. but i cant got their point of view.
they also uses word callback. what is it?

Comment: If you cannot understand function pointers and callbacks, what is the point of giving code?  You won't understand it.

Comment: What @AntonH says.  Suppose you need to use an async OS or library API that needs to call one of your functions later?

Comment: i know function pointer. but can't understand its application.

Comment: @AkashPatel Lots of examples if you think about it. For example, game AI. A creature will behave a certain way, ie, it received pointer to behaviour function. Depending on events (eg., creature gets attacked, or hears a noise), you can apply a new behavioural pattern to the creature by changing the pointer to function. So no `if ... else if ...` or `switch ... case`. That's just one example. You'll have to find others yourself for your C programming blog :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not actual need passing functions as parameters. But your example is rather didactic to make you understand how function pointers work.

However it's important to understand them as they might become very useful especially when dealing with  libraries loaded at runtime. There are tons of examples where function pointers are really a good tool.

Here's one:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

double doOperation(double arg, double (*func)(double))
{
    return (*func)(arg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    double (*cosine)(double);
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen ("/lib/libm.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    cosine = dlsym(handle, "cos");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("%f\n", doOperation(2.0, cosine);
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

You open a library, search for the **cosine** function, and then pass it as an argument to **doOperation**.

You can also look **[here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html)** for more info.

Comment: Added an example with a dynamic loaded library.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are used when you might need to change the behavior of your function call depending on some dynamic requirement.

[This](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) page sums it up short and sweet:

> A function pointer is a variable that stores the address of a function that can later be called through that function pointer. This is useful because functions encapsulate behavior. For instance, every time you need a particular behavior such as drawing a line, instead of writing out a bunch of code, all you need to do is call the function. But sometimes you would like to choose different behaviors at different times in essentially the same piece of code.

A few excellent examples are available there are well.

Comment: i am still not getting the point. Can you please give small code for this. or correct my code by making it perfect example for my question.
thanks...

Comment: Decaying rapidly towards a 'gimme teh codez' copy/paste homework answer.

Comment: Did you even bother following the links provided, either in this response or in the comments to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You pass a function [pointer] to another function because you want to dynamically direct *which* function the receiver calls.  Or more precisely, because the receiver function is built to allow you to do so, thereby requiring you to do so.  The pointed-to function does not need to be available at the time the receiver is compiled.

The comparison function required as a `qsort()` argument is the prototypical example.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Why pass a function to another function?

Without re-writing `bsort()`, code can sort more than 1 way by only changing the compare function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
int compare_up(int a,int b) {
    if(a > b) return 1;
    return -1;
}

int compare_down(int a,int b) {
    if(a < b) return 1; // reverse the compare
    return -1;
}

int compare_random(int a,int b) {
   return rand() & 1;  // mix them up
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int arr[5]={6,5,1,9,2};

    bsort(arr,5,compare_up);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]); puts("");

    bsort(arr,5,compare_down);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]); puts("");

    bsort(arr,5,compare_random);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]); puts("");

    return 0;
}
```