# what does &function_name depicts in the following code

Tags: c++

I have following code snippet, 
what does `&main` and `&user` depict here?
Each time I run why does it give different values?
In what scenarios passing &function_name is useful?

```
int user()
{
      return 0;  
}

int main()
{
    int a, b = 0;
    a = ((int)&main);
    b = ((int)&user);
    cout << a <<" " << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about function pointers in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: The use of function pointers is the only way to solve certain problems. It's useful in those scenarios.

Comment: In the examples above it depicts unspecified behavior.

Comment: I remember referring to `main` (or only calling it?) is UB. Whatever the source of this code, it's not good. Replace it with [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The C++ standards forbid any usage of the `main()` function in a program - including taking its address (as occurs with `&main` within the `main()` function).  The result of doing so gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140719/sbi) explained it nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592137/what-is-the-point-of-function-pointers):

> Most examples boil down to ***callbacks***: You call a function `f()`
>   passing the address of another function `g()`, and `f()` calls `g()`
>   for some specific task. If you pass `f()` the address of `h()`
>   instead, then `f()` will call back `h()` instead.
>
> Basically, this is a way to ***parametrize*** a function: Some part of
>   its behavior is not hard-coded into `f()`, but into the callback
>   function. Callers can make `f()` behave differently by passing
>   different callback functions. A classic is `qsort()` from the C
>   standard library that takes its sorting criterion as a pointer to a
>   comparison function.
>
> In C++, this is often done using ***function objects*** (also called
>   functors). These are objects that overload the function call operator,
>   so you can call them as if they were a function. Example:
>
> ```
> class functor {
>   public:
>      void operator()(int i) {std::cout << "the answer is: " << i << '\n';}
> };
>
> functor f;
> f(42);
> ```
>
> The idea behind this is that, unlike a function pointer, a function
>   object can carry not only an algorithm, but also data:
>
> ```
> class functor {
>   public:
>      functor(const std::string& prompt) : prompt_(prompt) {}
>      void operator()(int i) {std::cout << prompt_ << i << '\n';}
>   private:
>      std::string prompt_;
> };
>
> functor f("the answer is: ");
> f(42);
> ```
>
> Another advantage is that it is sometimes easier to inline calls to
>   function objects than calls through function pointers. This is a
>   reason why sorting in C++ is sometimes faster than sorting in C.

Answer (score 0):

It depcits the address of your functions. The reason why its different each time you run it, is because your program probably does not use the same memory space each time.

&main gives you the address of your main function, quite like &var gives you the address of a variable called var. The cast to int is probably problematic. Pointers on a 64 bit system are 64 bit wide, an int may not be that long.