# Is it effective to use function pointers in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

Does the function pointer affect the run time of the program?

```
int (*fptr1)(int);

int square(int num) {
    return num*num;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    fptr1 = square;
    printf("%d squared is %d\n",n, fptr1(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592137/what-is-the-point-of-function-pointers

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of hard to answer, since it's very low level, and it generally boils down to "it depends".

In general, assuming the function pointer is actually used, I would expect it to have a cost since it's an extra step. There's a difference between loading the value of a variable and then jumping there, compared to jumping to a constant location that is known at load-time. That cost will probably vary over the execution of the program, due to caching for instance, but it will likely never be zero. Also using a function pointer might of course allow the code to be structured in a way that makes it faster overall, so it can still be a positive.

For instance, consider:

```
for (a bajillion)
{
  if (something complex)
  {
    function1();
  }
  else
  {
    function2();
  }
}
```

this does the complex `if` a bajillion times, which of course will cost a lot. This can be refactored using function pointers:

```
const void (*function)(void) = (something complex) ? function1 : function2;
for (a bajillion times)
{
  function();
}
```

The latter code moves the `if` out of the loop by pre-computing which function to call, thus saving (a bajillion - 1) instances of the condition from ever being evaluated. This can be faster, even if the actual function call now is slower due to the extra indirection step.

For this *specific* case, compiling with optimization removes the call, and even removes the squaring itself since it's compile-time constant.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fact that it is far less likely that a compiler will inline the function, no.

Note that the *as-if* rule allows the compiler to generate code as if the source was

```
int main()
{
    printf("5 squared is 25\n");
}
```

epitomising the fact that many optimisations are best left to the compiler.

Comment: In *this* case? Seems inlinable enough https://godbolt.org/z/V3aS27

Comment: @StoryTeller: Wow, back to the original draft then.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
One of the major advantage of function pointers is runtime polymorphism.

You can use same function pointer to point to different functions with same signature.

Example:

```
int (*fptr1)(int);

int square(int num) {
 return num*num;
}

int cube(int num)
{
  return num*num*num;    
}

int main()
{
  int n = 5;

 fptr1 = square;
 printf("squre = %d\n", fptr1(n));

 fptr1 = cube;
 printf("cube= %d\n", fptr1(n));

  return 0;
}
```

Here `fptr1` is made to point to different functions(`square` and `cube`) based on the need.