# Using FnMut, Fn, FnOnce as arguments to a function

Tags: function, rust, parameters, parameter-passing, first-class-functions

I don't quite understand when/how a function can use bounds of types `Fn`, `FnOnce`, `FnMut`. Can someone explain in what scenario these would be used and how one would use them?

As I understand it, I can create a function like this:

```
struct Dog {
    name: String,
}

struct Cat {
    name: String,
}


fn foo(a: impl FnOnce(Dog) -> Cat) {
    // call a once
}
```

But why would I pass a function into another function? Is there some kind of advantage of doing so such as bypassing function visibility, etc.?

Comment: Look up the strategy pattern

Comment: Also: [What is the point of function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2592137/364696) This isn't language-specific, Rust just splits the types of functions up into broad categories to support the various compile-time safety features it provides, but simply being able to pass functions around is useful in all languages.

Comment: For some other search terms, in functional languages the concept is called "higher order functions".

Comment: Look at some of the functions in std::iter — they paint a pretty compelling picture of why you'd need to pass a function to another function.