# why do we need to call these functions at run time using function pointers. we can as well call them directly

Tags: c++, c, callback, function-pointers

Having read a bit about function pointers and callbacks, I fail to understand the basic purpose of it. To me it just looks like instead of calling the function directly we use the pointer to that function to invoke it. Can anybody please explain me callbacks and function pointers? How come the callback takes place when we use function pointers, because it seems we just call a function through a pointer to it instead of calling directly?

Thanks

ps: There have been some questions asked here regarding callbacks and function pointers but they do not sufficiently explain my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***What is a Callbak function?***
    In simple terms, a **Callback function** is one that is not called explicitly by the programmer. Instead, there is some mechanism that continually waits for events to occur, and it will call selected functions in response to particular events.
    This mechanism is typically used when a operation(function) can take long time for execution and the caller of the function does not want to wait till the operation is complete, but does wish to be intimated of the outcome of the operation. Typically, Callback functions help implement such an ***asynchronous mechanism***, wherein the caller registers to get inimated about the result of the time consuming processing and continuous other operations while at a later point of time, the caller gets informed of the result.

***An practical example:***
Windows event processing:
virtually all windows programs set up an event loop, that makes the program respond to particular events (eg button presses, selecting a check box, window getting focus) by calling a function. The handy thing is that the programmer can specify what function gets called when (say) a particular button is pressed, even though it is not possible to specify when the button will be pressed. The function that is called is referred to as a callback.

***An source Code Illustration:***

```
//warning:  Mind compiled code, intended to illustrate the mechanism    
#include <map>

typedef void (*Callback)();
std::map<int, Callback>  callback_map;

void RegisterCallback(int event, Callback function)
{
    callback_map[event] = function;
}

bool finished = false;

int GetNextEvent()
{
    static int i = 0;
    ++i;
    if (i == 5) finished = false;
}

void EventProcessor()
{
    int event;
    while (!finished)
    {
        event = GetNextEvent();
        std::map<int, Callback>::const_iterator it = callback_map.find(event);
        if (it != callback_map.end())    // if a callback is registered for event
        {
            Callback function = *it;
            if (function)   
            {
                (*function)();
            }
            else
            {
               std::cout << "No callback found\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

void Cat()
{
   std::cout << "Cat\n";
}

void Dog()
{
    std::cout << "Dog\n";
}

void Bird()
{
    std::cout << "Bird\n";
}

int main()
{
    RegisterCallBack(1, Cat);
    RegisterCallback(2, Dog);
    RegisterCallback(3, Cat);
    RegisterCallback(4, Bird);
    RegisterCallback(5, Cat);

    EventProcessor(); 
    return 0;
}
```

The above would output the following:

```
Cat  
Dog   
Cat  
Bird  
Cat
```

Hope this helps!

<sup>**Note:** This is from one of my previous answers, **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183847/callback-functions-in-c-c-c/6184236#6184236)**</sup>

Comment: Thanks Als. This explains the use of function pointer but callback is still elusive. Where the callback happens here. It seems we are just invoking the function we wanted to call.

Comment: The point is that in the example above, all but Cat, Dog and Bird can be part of something that you did not write yourself, that you don't have the source code of, or that you wanted to write in a generic way, i.e. that you don't have to modify it when suddenly you also decide to call Fish (or any of the other thousands of annimals)

Comment: @user52875 one more thing I understood that function pointer is a way to achieve abstraction.. I got your point. But what about callback?

Comment: @polapts: The point is that the "event loop" code doesn't need to know anything about the particular functions that are registered.  So this code always stays the same.  The *user* of this code can register whatever functions they like as callbacks, and the event loop will call them at the correct time.

Answer (score 4):

One very striking reason for why we need function pointers is that they allow us to call a function that the author of the calling code (that's us) does not know! A call-back is a classic example; the author of `qsort()` doesn't know or care about how you compare elements, she just writes the generic algorithm, and it's up to you to provide the comparison function.

But for another important, widely used scenario, think about dynamic loading of libraries - by this I mean loading at *run* time. When you write your program, you have no idea which functions exist in some run-time loaded library. You might read a text string from the user input and then open a user-specified library and execute a user-specified function! The only way you could refer to such function is via a pointer.

Here's a simple example; I hope it convinces you that you could not do away with the pointers!

```
typedef int (*myfp)();  // function pointer type

const char * libname = get_library_name_from_user();
const char * funname = get_function_name_from_user();

void * libhandle = dlopen(libname, RTLD_NOW);  // load the library
myfp fun = (myfp) dlsym(libhandle, funname);   // get our mystery function...

const int result = myfp();                     // ... and call the function
                                               // -- we have no idea which one!

printf("Your function \"%s:%s\" returns %i.\n", libname, funname, result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's for [decoupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727824/does-using-callbacks-in-c-increase-coupling/1727845#1727845). Look at [`sqlite3_exec()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) - it accepts a callback pointer that is invoked for each row retrieved. SQLite doesn't care of what your callback does, it only needs to know how to call it.

Now you don't need to recompile SQLite each time your callback changes. You may have SQLite compiled once and then just recompile your code and either relink statically or just restart and relink dynamically.

Comment: Look at `qsort` in the standard library.

Comment: Better example would be the predicate of `std::sort`, which is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

It also avoids name collision. If you have 2 libs, both do sorting and both expect you to define a function called `sort_criteria` that they can call, how would you sort 2 different objects types with the same function?

It would quickly get complicated following all the if's and switches in the `sort_criteria` function, with callbacks you can specify your own function (with their nice to interpret name) to those sort functions.